# Получить все года в которых опубликованы записи

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице постов хочу получить все года на которых опубликованы записи.
Использую сейчас функцию  `wp_get_archives()`. Но эта функция выдает то что нужно не так как нужно. 
Я делаю так: `wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'yearly', 'post_type' => 'events'));` и получаю года в разметке внутри тегов `<li>` и `<a>` а мне они нужны в виде строки или массива чтобы сделать кастомную разметку. Посоветуйте как это можно сделать!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взять за основу функцию `wp_get_archives` выкинув из неё всё лишнее (там всё более-менее понятно).

Либо напрямую дёрнуть данные из MySQL, но это не самый аккуратный вариант.

```
SELECT
 YEAR(post_date) AS `year`,
 count(ID) as posts
FROM
 wp_posts
WHERE
 post_type = 'events' AND post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY
 YEAR(post_date)
ORDER BY
 post_date;
```

Comment: Вот за запрос отдельное спасибо) Так и сделал, но там ссылки мешают. Мне нужно GET запрос через ссылку.

Comment: Запрос почти полностью скопипащен из кода функции `wp_get_archives` https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1638